How to find the order and type of Mittag-Leffler Function?
I'm reading up on some properties of the Mittag-Leffler Function, which is defined by
$$
E_{\alpha, \beta}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\beta)}, \quad z \in \mathbb{C} .
$$
One of the properties is:
For $\alpha>0$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}, E_{\alpha, \beta}(z)$ is entire of order $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and type 1.
where the order $\rho$ and the corresponding type of an entire function $f(z)$ are defined respectively by
$$
\rho:=\lim \sup _{R \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left(\ln \max _{|z| \leq R}|f(z)|\right)}{\ln R} \quad \text { and } \quad \limsup _{R \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \max _{|z| \leq R}|f(z)|}{R^\rho} .
$$
Below is the proof from the book.
It suffices to show that the Mittag-Leffler Function converges for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Using Stirling's formula ：
$\Gamma(z)=(2 \pi)^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-z} z^{z-\frac{1}{2}}\left(1+O\left(z^{-1}\right)\right) \quad$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty,|\arg (z)|<\pi-\epsilon$.
we have
$$
\frac{\Gamma((k+1) \alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(k \alpha+\beta)}=(k \alpha)^\alpha\left(1+O\left(k^{-1}\right)\right) \quad \text { as } k \rightarrow \infty .
$$
Thus, by Cauchy's criterion, the series converges for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$. The order and type of $E_{\alpha, \beta}(z)$ follow similarly.
I don’t understand why convergence over the entire complex plane allows us to determine the order and type.
Can you give me some references and tips, thanks a lot!

The proof shows that the function is indeed entire. Thus, one can talk about the order and type of the Mittag-Leffler function. One still needs to determine what those are.

there are simple formulas for the order and type of an entire functions in terms of the coefficients and Stirling applied to those immediately gives the result (eg order is given by $\limsup \frac{n \log n}{-\log |a_n|}$ and $-\log |a_n|=\log \Gamma(\alpha n+\beta)$ at least for $n$ large enough and that is clearly asymptotic to $\alpha n \log n$ etc
